# Problem with content unpublish in Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1

Tags: 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion

We are having problems with unpublishing the content of any Tridion publication. When we try to unpublish any content, these unpublished elements do not disappear from the application of the front and remain in the file system. After unpublishing the content, we have verified the following actions:

- In the Tridion publishing queue, the content has been successfully unpublished, giving Success in the queue.
- It is verified that the icon next to the element that indicates if an
  the element is published, also disappears.
- In the "Where used" tab, it does not appear that the item is
  published in any target.
- Finally, check that in the Broker the unpublished content has also
  disappeared.

As we have commented previously, the problem of unpublish occurs with any publication of Tridion, therefore, we discard the problem of advertising or the application in particular. The permissions have also been revised in the front applications are correct.

On the other hand, when we publish any content, it works correctly, updating this published element with the content and the correct date of the publication in front of the application.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Pablo.

Comment: Can you check is there any error in your deployer logs or enable TRACE logs in your deployer and troubleshoot what is going on? I could think of your ItemTypes maybe something not correctly defined for filesystem or deployer service app pool not having permission.

Comment: Can you also try to create a new page and publish to the web application to check is that new page is appearing or not?

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan ,
First, we reviewed the deployer's log file and there was no record.
I followed the steps you told me, creating a new page, publishing it successfully, but the problem is when I want to unpublish. As I said, the whole process is correct except for the step of removing the file from the file system.
Regards,

Comment: then seems to be a permission issue, double check that folder has permission to deployer app pool has to delete the file from a file system?

Comment: Increase the logging level of the Deployer in the logback.xml file, restart the Deployer and check in the logs for anything unusual.

Comment: if not help run Procmon.exe to process monitor what's going for deleting the file with the process?

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comments and chat with Velu, I don't think that this is file permission problem. If deployer tried to delete file, and failed to do so, it would 100% report the problem, and say, Hey, I cannot delete the file. In that case, transaction will have failed status, not success as it looks like.

The problem here is most probably that deployer has no info that it should delete the file, or thinks that file shouldn't be deleted.

So let's tackle the first problem:

If deployer has no idea that it should delete the file, its most probably that it received such action from Resolver in resolving instructions. In this case, I would take a look at transport package, and check if there is action to delete this page. If there is no such instruction, you must additionally check Resolver side to see why is it so (maybe custom resolver is making issues, or some event system on unpublish).

As for the second problem:

In this case deployer thinks that it cannot remove the file, because its being used on some other place (for example it has reference is some other CP and so on). Although it received information to delete it, it found out that item is somewhere else used, so it just removed one reference for broker. For this, you must enable trace logs in deployer app and analyze the broker database for references.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community Pablo. At a high-level, SDL Tridion publishing (Publisher, transporter and deployer) only takes care of packages the items from the content manager and making them available or unavailable in the storage layers being configured, out of the box.

In your question, you mention **"unpublished elements do not disappear from the application of the front and remain in the file system"**. You additionally confirm **"Finally, check that in the Broker the unpublished content has also disappeared"**

Based on the above, it looks like SDL Tridion publishing is working as expected during unpublishing a file i.e; it processes the instructions from the content manager and removes the files from the storage, which is the broker in your case.

It does look like your Tridion content delivery application, which may NOT be a SDL product, is not removing the file from the filesystem. Ensuring that cache is properly invalidated could be an issue with any extensions that may have been configured for SDL Tridion publishing as well.

In order for us to properly answer your question:

- Can you also update the query that was being used to confirm that the item has been removed from the broker?
- Does the issue happen for pages or does it happen ONLY for binaries (multimedia)?
- Can you update your question with more information on your "front end
  application"? Do you have a custom application (any information will
  help)?
- Can you explain if the caching logic implemented in your
  "frond end application"? How does the file in the broker get the
  filesystem? What is the cache invalidation logic being set?
- Does the issue happen for pages or does it happen ONLY for binaries (multimedia)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to troubleshoot that unpublishing issue:

1. When you un-publish the Page, check that the (un)publish package is arriving in the `incoming` folder on the expected Deployer server correctly.
2. Double-check that the database/file folder path that you are referring to is definitely the correct one. sometimes we look at the wrong Broker database/path (e.g Staging instead of Live), or in the wrong environment (e.g. TEST instead of Prod).
3. Increase the logging level of the Deployer in the **logback.xml** file, restart the Deployer and check in the logs for anything unusual.
4. Confirm that the instruction to unpublish the Page is definitely in the (un)publish a package that lands in the Deployer's `incoming` folder. This could be caused, for example, by a Custom Resolver that prevents certain pages from being unpublished. (As @Marko mentioned Custom Resolvers prevent the page from being unpublished).
5. You could run a process monitor (Procmon.exe) to double check what is going on.
6. If none of the above work, you could run a SQL Trace on the Broker database to ensure that a SQL query to remove the offending records is run

Failing that all the options I would suggest that you log a case with Tridion Support.

I hope that it helps.